# removeFromSuperview not working after calling Facebook login

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i know there are a lot of other answers on here but i can't seem to find one that works for my specific problem. I have a view controller, where i check for Facebook session. If no active session, i run the following where the user has the option to login with Facebook:

```
    FacebookViewController *goFacebook = [[FacebookViewController alloc]init];
    goFacebook = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Facebook"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:goFacebook animated:NO];
```

After logging in the user is returned to Facebook view controller where i run:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(appDidEnterForeground:) name:UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification object:nil];
```

and

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ///to return user to original view.
```

Once returned to original view controller my code then runs to populate the tableview, where I have a UIView (searchView) which is added with this code:

```
    self.loadIndicator =  [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 40, 40)];
    self.loadIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge;
    self.loadIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = YES;

    self.loadingText = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(40, 0, 275, 60)];
    self.loadingText.text = @"Loading your items...";
    self.loadingText.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.loadingText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Gill Sans" size:24];
    self.loadingText.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.loadingText.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.loadingText.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    searchView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240, 300, 300, 60)];
    searchView.alpha = 1.0;
    searchView.opaque = YES;
    searchView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(36.0/255.0) green:(147.0/255.0) blue:(195.0/255.0) alpha:1];
    searchView.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;

    [m_tableView2 addSubview:searchView];        
    [searchView addSubview:self.loadingText];
    [searchView addSubview:self.loadIndicator];
    [self.loadIndicator startAnimating];
```

which i attempt to remove by:

```
[self.searchView removeFromSuperview];
```

which does not remove searchView. Nor does:

```
[self.searchView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
```

I'm sure i'm gonna get hammered and down voted for this but i'm not finding the right answer that solves my problem here. Any help is greatly appreciated though.

Comment: The only invitation to hammering in the question is the phrase "does not work".  It would be great to see the declaration and initialization of searchView, things that happen on another view controller -- like the Facebook one -- hardly seem to matter.

Comment: I notice that you don't assign self.searchView when you create it.  There's a decent chance that you're sending removeFromSuperview to nil.

Comment: cutting and pasting error. see where i add [m_tableView2 addSubview:searchView];

Comment: sure, but I wasn't asserting that you didn't add it to a superview, I'm suggesting you didn't assign it to a property of the view controller.  See how you say `searchView = [[UIView alloc] ...` what is that searchView?  Notice how that line doesn't mention `self`?

Comment: Breakpoint at and inspect (or NSLog) self.searchView at the point just before you remove it.  Is it nil?  I'd wager yes.

Comment: Here is what is in NSLog: HERE IS WHAT IS IN SEARCHVIEW <UIView: 0x1902ef60; frame = (260 300; 250 60); layer = <CALayer: 0x19037c60>>

Comment: Then my theory is no good. What happens if you say self.searchView.alpha = 0;  instead of removeFromSuperview?  It should disappear , right?

Comment: Also, when my view does have active Facebook session, then the table loads and searchView does get removed. So, it seemed like it has something to do with bouncing out to Facebook login and coming back. Thats why i tried the "performSelectorOnMainThread" but that also did not work.

Comment: so, i tried self.searchView.alpha = 0; but that does not seem to get invoked either.

Comment: Just noticed that the parent is called m_tableView2.  Is that a UITableView?  Very strange to add a subview to a table view.  Are you maybe really needing a UIRefreshControl?  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/

Answer (score 0):

Call removeFromSuperView on main thread i hope it works.

Comment: You mean like this? [self.searchView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO]; If so, i have tried that as mentioned above and that did not work.